# an if statement not working properly in a certain app I wrote

Tags: if-statement

so I was writing this phonebook in python and I wanted the app to check if two people are sharing the same email/phone number but it's not working properly

```
phonebook = dict()
c = 0 
while True:
    if c >= 1:
        print("type 'done' if you want to end the program\n")
    while True:
          name = input("please enter the name you want this contact to be saved with\n")
          name = name.lower()
          if name in phonebook:
               print("you can't have two names exactly like eachother in the same phonebook!\n")
               continue
          else:
               break
    if name == "done":
        break
    
    while True:
          try:
               num = input("Please enter this person's number (without a zero)\n")
               if num in phonebook.values():
                    print("this number is already in your phonebook!\n")
                    continue
               else:
                    break
          except:
               print("Please enter a valid number\n")
               continue
    while True:
          email = input("Please enter this person's email\n")
          if "@" not in email or " " in email:
               print("this email was not valid please re-enter the info\n")
               continue
          elif email in phonebook.values():
               print("please enter a email that has not been used before!")
               continue
          else:
               phonebook[name] = (num, email)
               c += 1
               break
print(phonebook)
count = 0 
while True:
    if count == 0:
          print("Great! we have your phonebook ready to go!\nenter a name and we will give you their info!\n(type exit to close the program)\n")
    else:
         print("enter a name and we will give you their info!\n(type exit to close the program)\n")
    given_name = input()
    given_name = given_name.lower()
    if given_name == "exit":
          break
    if given_name not in phonebook:
          ("that name's not in the phonebook")
          continue
    print(phonebook.get(given_name))
    count += 1
    continue
```

this is the full code of the program and the issues i mentioned are happening in lines 33 and 20 where I was expecting the program to actually tell me if two contacts are sharing the same phone number/email but it's not.